# list index out of range when crawling data and adjust data

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, request, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl data from a list of url (1st loop) . And in each url (2nd loop), I want to adjust the product_reviews['reviews'] ( list) by adding more data. Here is my code :

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\ids.xlsx')
ids = df['ids'].values.tolist() 
link = 'https://www.real.de/product/%s/'
url_test = 'https://www.real.de/pdp-test/api/v1/%s/product-attributes/?offset=0&limit=500'
url_test1 = 'https://www.real.de/pdp-test/api/v1/%s/product-reviews/?offset=0&limit=500'


for i in ids:
    
    product_id = requests.get(url_test %i).json()
    product_reviews = requests.get(url_test1 %i).json()
    
    for x in range(0,len(product_reviews['reviews']),1):
        product_reviews['reviews'][x]['variantAttributes'].append(str(int(100*float(product_reviews['reviews'][x]['variantAttributes'][1]['label'].replace(" m","").replace(",",".")))))
        product_reviews['reviews'][x]['variantAttributes'].append(str(int(100*float(product_reviews['reviews'][x]['variantAttributes'][0]['label'].replace(" m","").replace(",","."))))) 
        product_reviews['reviews'][x]['size']= str(int(100*float(product_reviews['reviews'][x]['variantAttributes'][1]['label'].replace(" m","").replace(",","."))))+ 'x' + str(int(100*float(product_reviews['reviews'][x]['variantAttributes'][0]['label'].replace(" m","").replace(",","."))))
        product_reviews['reviews'][x]['url'] = link %i
        product_reviews['reviews'][x]['ean'] = product_id['defaultAttributes'][0]['values'][0]['text']
        product_reviews['reviews'][x]['TotalReviewperParent'] =  product_reviews['totalReviews']
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(product_reviews['reviews'])
    df.to_excel( r'C:\new\str(i).xlsx', index=False)
```

However when I run this code, it returns error :

> line 24, in 
> product_reviews['reviews'][x]['variantAttributes'].append(str(int(100*float(product_reviews['reviews'][x]['variantAttributes'][1]['label'].replace(" m","").replace(",",".")))))

> IndexError: list index out of range

When I run the 2nd loop for 1 url, it runs fine, however when I put 2nd loop inside 1st loop, it returns error. What is the solution for it ? And my code seems so monkey. Do you know how to improve my code so it can be shorter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, in the future, try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't have access to your 'ids.xlsx' so we can't verify if the problem is with a specific id in your list or a general problem.

Taking a random id, `338661983`, and using the following code:

```
import requests

link = 'https://www.real.de/product/%s/'
url_attributes = 'https://www.real.de/pdp-test/api/v1/%s/product-attributes/?offset=0&limit=500'
url_reviews = 'https://www.real.de/pdp-test/api/v1/%s/product-reviews/?offset=0&limit=500'

ids = [338661983]

for i in ids:
    
    product_id = requests.get(url_attributes % i).json()
    product_reviews = requests.get(url_reviews % i).json()

    for review in product_reviews['reviews']:
      print(review)
      break
```

I get the following output:

```
{'reviewId': 1119427, 'title': 'Klasse!', 'date': '11.11.2020', 'rating': 5, 'isVerifiedPurchase': True, 'text': 'Originale Switch, schnelle Lieferung. Alles Top ', 'variantAttributes': [], 'author': 'hm-1511917085', 'datePublished': '2020-11-11T20:09:41+01:00'}
```

Notice that `variantAttributes` is an empty list.
You get an IndexError because you try to take the element at position 1 of that empty list in:

```
review['variantAttributes'][1]['label'].replace(" m","").replace(",",".")
```